# gdcm library - transfer syntax

Tags: gdcm

Does GDCM library support the following DICOM transfer syntaxes:

1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.53  JPEG Spectral Selection, Nonhierarchical (Processes 6 & 8)
1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.55  JPEG Full Progression, Nonhierarchical (Processes 10 & 12)

If yes, could anyone link me sample pictures encoded with these transfer syntaxes? I've been searching everywhere, but I found nothing...

---

Thanks for your reply.
I have already seen that link you provided, but there is no Transfer Syntax UIDs list, so I wasn't sure GDCM supports exactly transfer syntaxes I mentioned in my question.

Still, I need to test it in practice, so still looking for files encoded with those transfer syntaxes... Searched over 20k pictures and didn't find them, but I know there must be somewhere example files..

Answer (score 1):

Yes GDCM does support both of those, see [Short Presentation](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gdcm/index.php?title=Main_Page#Short_Presentation)